# Is promoting workers to conveyors (=> affecting them to a warehouse) more interesting than keeping them working where they are?

Tags: against-the-storm

If I understand well the terminology, when I affect one worker to a warehouse, he becomes a conveyor.

Today, I wait for all my production buildings to be built, filled with workers, and then only I start filling warehouse slots to create conveyors.
But am I wise? I guess not.

I'm wondering : if I have some workers,
but yet not enough to fill all my production and harvest places,
- let's say that I have 10 workers, but 13 slots in harvesting camps and production buildings, so that they are 3 free places left unoccupied -

When a new villager comes, the eleventh one,
is it more interesting for me to assign him:

- at a 11th working slot
- or at the first free slot available in a warehouse?

What will prove the most helpful?